# Fetching data by comparing single value with comma-delimited records in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, select

I am trying to fetch posts data of the particular author from database.
I have to fetch data as per post_author.
post_author field contain data like -

2,4,5,9
 2,4,5
 4
4
4
2,4,10

If the post having multiple authors then values stored in comma-delimited format.
I want to compare post_author(stored in session admin_id) with field post_author.
if suppose I have a post_author 4, that is available in all records, so select query should return all records.
My select query in model -

```
$this->db->select('p.ID,p.post_date,p.post_title,p.post_url,u.user_login');
$this->db->from('sa_posts p,sa_users u');
$this->db->where('u.ID=p.post_author');
$this->db->where('p.post_author',$this->session->userdata('admin_id')); // Here is a problem to compare post_author.
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Something's not clear to me, are there multiple authors in a comma-delimited format being stored in your db field?

Comment: @alaric. Yeah you are right. It post_author may be one or more than one.

Comment: Leaving aside for a moment that you shouldn't store data in that manner... what does it currently return when you have only one post author in the field?

Comment: @alaric If there is only one post_author, query returns that record but the values are in comma-delimited format, then this query don't fetch such records.

Comment: As expected with that query.  Your query is essentially attempting to match anything equaling the provided p.post_author.  When there are multiple, comma-delimited values it doesn't equal it.  While you could query it in that way it would be better to change the format of the database a bit.

Comment: I'll post the best solution as a response in a min.

Comment: @alaric I can't change the format of database table. If suppose I added new post my post_author would be inserted in post_author. Later admin have the authority to add other users to that post. In that case I have to store post_author in comma delimited format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139120/discussion-between-deepak-and-alaric).

Answer (score 2):

Try the following in CodeIgniter:

Substitute:

```
$this->db->where('p.post_author',$this->session->userdata('admin_id'));
```

for:

```
$this->db->where(FIND_IN_SET("{$this->session->userdata('admin_id')}", 'p.post_author') != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

After making some changes I got the output what I wanted using FIND_IN_SET()-

```
$where = "FIND_IN_SET('".$this->session->userdata('admin_id')."', p.post_author)";

$this->db->select('p.ID,p.post_date,p.post_title,p.post_url,u.user_login');
$this->db->from('sa_posts p,sa_users u');
$this->db->where('u.ID=p.post_author');
$this->db->where( $where );
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```